# How do I escape javascript errors running on a remote script that I don't control

Tags: javascript, events, internet-explorer-8

I have client who uses his own tracking package which attaches listeners to all types of events. At least one of them produces an error in IE8 and prevents actions that I have scripted to occur for the same event.

Is there a way of catching these errors gracefully? I tried event.stopPropagation() but that didn't seem to help.

Thank you

Comment: How about including the script within IE conditional tags `<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->script<!--<![endif]-->`

Comment: I am supposed to unconditionally include the tracking script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror):

```
window.onerror = null;
```

But that might give you unfounded confidence that there are no *other* errors in the code.

Comment: I'm not surprised.  This disables the reporting of errors but doesn't prevent them from occurring.  You probably need to determine each error that occurs in IE8 and come up with a work-around.